# JavaScript code fails to render partials on form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I need help troubleshooting some JavaScript in my Rails 4 application. My goal is to improve user experience by only showing relevant form fields for different types of cardio exercises that a user may select.

For example, if a user selects "Cycling", I want a partial named "_cardio_time.erb" to show "distance," "predicted pace," and "duration" fields. If a user selects say "Jumping Jack", I want a partial named _cardio_sets to show "sets" and "reps" fields.

Here's my attempt at writing the JavaScript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#cardio_exercise_aerobic_training_list_id").change(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
  $("<% if cardio_exercise.aerobic_training_list.category == 1 %>");
  $("<%= escape_javascript render(:partial => 'layouts/cardio_time.erb' %>").insertAfter('#read-cardio-exercise-description-text');
  $("<% else %>");
  $("<%= escape_javascript render(:partial => 'layouts/cardio_sets.erb' %>").insertAfter('#read-cardio-exercise-description-text');
  $("<% end %>");
  })    
});
```

The code does not generate any errors in the Firebug console, but when I select "Cycling" from the drop-down menu, the following text is rendered on the form:

```
<%= escape_javascript render(:partial => 'layouts/cardio_sets.erb' %><%= escape_javascript render(:partial => 'layouts/cardio_time.erb' %>
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm learning Rails and JavaScript. I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#cardio_exercise_aerobic_training_list_id").change(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        <% if cardio_exercise.aerobic_training_list.category == 1 %>
        $("<%= escape_javascript render(:partial => 'layouts/cardio_time.erb') %>").insertAfter('#read-cardio-exercise-description-text');
        <% else %>
        $("<%= escape_javascript render(:partial => 'layouts/cardio_sets.erb') %>").insertAfter('#read-cardio-exercise-description-text');
        <% end %>
    })    
});
```

See if removing jQuery wrapper for if/then/end sentences, and adding a missing bracket on the end of `render` solves the issue.

Comment: Thanks for reply Niloct.  I'm getting a syntax error in Firebug now:  SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'  <% if cardio_exercise.aerobic_training_list.category == "1"  Looks like it's got some kind of problem with the Ruby "<%" expression ... any ideas why?

Comment: Because ruby is not being interpreted. The ruby script is being output as raw text and not run.

Comment: Niloct, any suggestions for how I might troubleshoot the problem further?  What could cause the Ruby script to not run? Is the JavaScript okay or do I need to look elsewhere in my application to track down why the script isn't executing?  Sounds like I've got to learn some more.

Comment: Well... that could be a long debugging situation. Have you configured ruby on the machine you serve this page ? What is the page extension (i.e. page.rb, page.html etc...) ? You can't serve processed Ruby script code without configuring a Ruby server.

Comment: Ruby is configured. The file extension is .js.erb in the assets pipeline folder; the partials in view/layouts. Got an undefined method render error. After more research, I learned that "render" isn't available from the assets pipeline. So far, no luck with the file in the view folder either. I need to do more research. I'll try to get some help @ a local Rails meet-up. You're probably right: this could be a long debugging situation. Although I still don't know what's wrong & how to fix it, I want to give you credit for pointing out issues with my JavaScript syntax. What do you think is fair?

Comment: Great, you know where you're going! Now I will have to duplicate your environment here to try to reproduce the issue (or study more rails)